# Store Shipping Times

Tags: magento

We would like to store the shipping time of each shipment in our Magento (1.3.2.4) store. We don't want to have to recalculate this each time from the 'track's. What would be a good way to do this? We want to be able to do `Mage::getModel(sales/order_shipment)->load($id)->setShippingTime($tme);` and then later on do `Mage::getModel(sales/order_shipment)->load($id)->getShippingTime();`. However, where would we store that information? We don't see a shipping table. Is it part of the EAV goodness of the Sales tables? If its EAV, I think it should be easy to make an install script that adds the 'column'. But if it isn't EAV, then I don't want to mess with core files. Should I just make a new table with `shipment_id` and `shipment_time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to add a field to sales_flat_order and save the time to order collection and then you can ask this every time from order by field name or make your own method to acquire this data